# What players have the highest vertical reach

Tags: nba

What players currently playing in the NBA (2011-12) have the highest measured vertical reach?

And what players historically have had the highest vertical reach?

I find lots of rumours on the net, but is there a definitive source?

Comment: For the record, I know about James White [almost reaching 13 ft](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ElTzC2M34cY) and technically he has played in the NBA, although very limited minutes.

Comment: This just isn't a constructive question for an SE site. Not sure how trivia really fits, but this isn't it.

Answer (score 4):

Sport Science did an episode about Dwight Howard and his vertical reach.  In that episode, they claim that Shaq held the record at 12'5" and Dwight Howard hit 12'6" ... You can see the segment [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w8Wiq-POmFA&feature=related).

There is also a video of a college player purportedly hitting 12'9" . You can see that video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FbVJ1IvYkaI).

I can't find a definitive list that has everything listed concisely, but I would venture to say that young, athletic centers are going to dominate the top end of that list.